# How to set automatic folding of newcommands and usepackages in vim?

Tags: vim, rubber

How do I set automatic folding of packages outside of document and new commands inside of documents?

If I use `{{{ }}}` marker around newcommand it ignores the command and says undefined control sequence.

Similar thing happens if I use it around `\usepackage`.

I am using vim, basicTex, mac, rubber.

Example:

```
{{{
\newcommand{\ime}[3]{
    \newpage
    {\Large \textbf{#1}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1} \hfill 
    \lhead{Čas priprave: #2}
    \rhead{Količina: #3}
    }
}}}
```

This ignores my new command.

Comment: I don't know about automatic folding, but you should comment your fold markers : `%{{{` and `%}}}`, otherwise they will be read by TeX.

Comment: Also, you can put your opening fold marker at the end of the `\newcommand` line, so as to have a title to your fold. *(that is `\newcommand{\ime}[3]{%{{{`)*

Comment: Commenting the fold marker works and it solved the problem. How do I mark thread as solved?

Comment: I'll answer if that's enough for you.

Comment: [vi.sx](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) exists.

Comment: @MartinSchröder It is a (somewhat) LaTeX question, as the code did not compile properly...

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about automatic folding, but you should comment your fold markers : `%{{{` and `%}}}`, otherwise they will be read by TeX.

Also, you can put your opening fold marker at the end of the `\newcommand` line, so as to have a title to your fold.

[image]

Your code would then look like :

```
\newcommand{\ime}[3]{%{{{
    \newpage
    {\Large \textbf{#1}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1} \hfill 
    \lhead{Čas priprave: #2}
    \rhead{Količina: #3}
    }
%}}}
```

Cheers,